# Given distinct value from a column in pandas dataframe, How can I creat a list from multiple rows/columns?

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe

Here is a piece from a large dataframe.

```
ss = {'EventCode': pd.Series(['Goal Away', 'Goal Away', 'Goal Home', 'Goal Away','Goal Home', 'Goal Home', 'Cancel Goal Home', 'Goal Home','Goal Home', 'Goal Away', 'Goal Away', 'Goal Home','Goal Away', 'Goal Home', 'Goal Away', 'Goal Home']),
'Team1_Goal': pd.Series([2,2,2,2,2,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]),
'Team2_Goal': pd.Series([3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,4,4,4,4,4]),
'xG_Team1': pd.Series([1.44344827512893,1.44344827512893,1.44344827512893,1.44344827512893,1.44344827512893,2.665637391386118,2.665637391386118,1.1554900289157282,1.1554900289157282,1.1554900289157282,1.1554900289157282,1.1554900289157282,1.1554900289157282,1.1554900289157282,1.1554900289157282,1.1554900289157282]),
'xG_Team2': pd.Series([1.5713173919057721,1.5713173919057721,1.5713173919057721,1.5713173919057721,1.5713173919057721,0.5207680077479664,0.5207680077479664,1.7456786951765073,1.7456786951765073,1.7456786951765073,1.7456786951765073,1.7456786951765073,1.7456786951765073,1.7456786951765073,1.7456786951765073,1.7456786951765073]),
'new_col1': pd.Series([0,0,179,0,190,123,0,29,75,0,0,118,0,143,0,190]),
'new_col2':pd.Series([100,163,0,181,0,0,0,0,0,97,112,0,140,0,186,0])}

df = pd.DataFrame(ss)
```

I have a function that takes an individual values from xG_Team1 and xG_Team2(paired). which works perfectly.

```
x1 = [1,0,0] 
x2 = [0,1,0] 
x3 = [0,0,1]

# Constants
total_timeslot = 180
m = 1
k = 180
Home_Goal = [] # No Goal
Away_Goal = [] # No Goal

def sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y):
    ssd = []
    for k in range(total_timeslot):  # k will take multiple values
        if k in Home_Goal:
            ssd.append(sum((x2 - y) ** 2))
        elif k in Away_Goal:
            ssd.append(sum((x3 - y) ** 2))
        else:
            ssd.append(sum((x1 - y) ** 2))
    return ssd

def my_function(row):
    xG_Team1 = row.xG_Team1
    xG_Team2 = row.xG_Team2
    return np.array([1-(xG_Team1*m + xG_Team2*m)/k, xG_Team1*m/k, xG_Team2*m/k])

results = df.apply(lambda row: sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, my_function(row)), axis=1)

results
```

The problem is the above function works only when Home and Away_Goal are zero or empty list.
I want to assign values to Home and Away Goal from `new_col1` and `new_col2` respectively for the same paired `xG_Team1` & `xG_Team2` used in the above function.

For example for `xG_Team1 = 1.44344827512893
and xG_Team2 =  1.5713173919057721`  ,

```
Home_goal =[179, 190], Away_Goal = [100, 163, 181]
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do

Comment: @BarthelemyPavy please see the edited post.

Comment: Please share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular share with us your `df.to_dict()` so people could easily reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that:

```
df['new_col'] = df['new_col1'] + df['new_col2']
result = df.groupby(['xG_Team1','xG_Team2','EventCode'])['new_col'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Where result is a new dataframe with column `new_col` that contains list of `Goal Away`, `Goal Home` per `xG_Team`

Out:

```
    xG_Team1    xG_Team2    EventCode          new_col
0   1.155490    1.745679    Goal Away          [97, 112, 140, 186]
1   1.155490    1.745679    Goal Home          [29, 75, 118, 143, 190]
2   1.443448    1.571317    Goal Away          [100, 163, 181]
3   1.443448    1.571317    Goal Home          [179, 190]
4   2.665637    0.520768    Cancel Goal Home   [0]
5   2.665637    0.520768    Goal Home          [123]
```

Comment: So this dataframe consists only columns I need to run the above function. Which is perfect. So how can I create Home_Goal and Away_Goal in the above function?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you want, can you show us your final dataframe or your final result ?

Comment: Yes, I will take a look but I'm a little bit busy now at work.